# Wordpress Mobile Edition, Wordpress Mobile Pack, WPTouch - Which one and how?

Tags: wordpress

First of all, Happy New Year!

I am thinking about making my blog accessible and enjoyable on mobile devices (as many handsets as possible). I am using Wordpress 3.0.4.

What I've found is couple of cool plugins like WPTouch (for touch enabled devices), The Wordpress Mobile Edition and the Wordpress Mobile Pack.

I am wondering which one is the best to use if I can use only one. If I can use more or (even all these three) are they compatible?

Does anyone have any experiences in this topic? If so I would much appreciate some advices or best practice links.

Happy 2011, thanks in advance, Rob

Answer (score 3):

WPTouch seems like the most reliable one, since many use it. Also some big blogs like TechCruch use is this.

Wptouch is reliable and compatible with a lot of devices.

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is a little dated, but...
I use Wordpress Mobile Edition. I have found no problems with it. Works great on my iPod Touch and iPad.

I think the best thing to do with any plugins are to try them out first.